# How to use this while inside of a Runnable defined on the fly

Tags: java, android, runnable

I have the following code:

```
public void setupScreen()
{
    view.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            view.setContentView(R.layout.game);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.game_layout);
            ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

This method is inside of a class that implements OnGlobalLayoutListener. I want to reference the class so i can put it as the parameter for the addOnGlobalLayoutListener() method. The problem is, is that when you reference **this** inside of a Runnable that is defined on the fly, **this** references the Runnable instead of the class I'm trying to reference. What is the work around for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you try `NameOfYourClass.this`?

Answer (score 1):

`YourActivityName.this`, or perhaps `YourClassName.this`. Last one is untested, and I don't have Android's SDK here to test.